# How to combine for loop with if condition

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I have below code:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
found = False
for l in lst:
    if l > 3:
        found = True
print(found)
```

Above code I am just checking if there is any item, greater than 3. Is it possible to convert above code in one liner something like below:

```
if l > 3 for l in lst:
```

Is it possible to combine for loops with if conditions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the above in

```
print([x for x in lst if x>3])
```

and would get the same output. Or you could also try

```
if [x for x in lst if x>3]:
   print("Ok")
```

Comment: This doesn't give the same output.